# the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it WITH binding

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml

I am getting this error when calling the setter of a Dp from a new thread. In the codes below `qqQuote` will update by itself; and In xaml I have `<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastAsk...>` Do I need a dispather here if I am not calling any Ui element from code behind?

```
public  static readonly  DependencyProperty LastAskProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LastAsk", typeof(double), typeof(ClickTradeViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(Double.NaN));

void  IDropable.Drop(object data, int index)
{
    ...
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IBQuoteSource.ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(temp, contract, "", false);
        LastAsk = qqQuote.Ask;
        LastBid = qqQuote.Bid;
        if (LastAsk != 0.0 && LastBid != 0.0)
            Spread = qqQuote.Ask - qqQuote.Bid;

    });
 }
```

Comment: As far as I know, because you have a UI element bound to something that is being modified in a different thread, I believe you do need the Dispatcher. Have you tried it with a Dispatcher? Does it work?

Comment: Nothing in Run is a UI element or created by the main thread?

Comment: See "DependencyObject and threading" on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.aspx -- Only code that runs on the UI thread can change or even read the value of a dependency property. For example a worker thread that you've initiated with a .NET Task or an explicit ThreadPool thread won't be able to read dependency properties or call other APIs.